# When I add a new cell in a defined range, it gets added to the formula, but when i add it at the end it does not get added

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

When I add a new cell in a defined range, it gets added to the formula, but when i add it at the end it does not get added as it is now outside of the range.

[image: see example in link]

so when I add a cell In e.g F8 the whole range automatically expands the range. but if I add a cell above F17 it is outside of the defined range and it does not get included in the count.
any thoughts on how no matter how many cells I add it will automatically get counted?

Answer (score 1):

You may use **table** feature of Excel. Define your range (*B2:K16*) as a table by clicking **Insert > Table** menu. After converting your into a table rewrite your formulas, while selecting range (e.g. *F3:F16*), you will see it is defined as *Table[25-May]*. From that point, you can add as many rows as you need to that table. The colmunn reference remains same but its size gets increased.